# Chart js 2.8 - How to make bars grow at the same speed?

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

Please, I need some help to make some suspense in showing poll final results in my chartjs canvas.

The bars have the same duration speed relative to their value, how to set the duration speed to each bar in the chart?

1. 1st step 4 bars at 36%
2. 2nd step 3 bars at 48%
3. Final Step 1 bar at 60%

**This is my chart**

[image]

**This my chartjs code**

```
        var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: data,
            options: {
                animation:{
                    duration : 6000,
                },
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        gridLines: {
                            show: false,
                            display:false,
                            drawBorder: false,
                            lineWidth: 0,
                            drawOnChartArea: false
                        },
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true,
                            display: false,
                            maxTicksLimit: 5,
                        }
                    }],
                    xAxes: [{
                        gridLines: {
                            show: false,
                            lineWidth: 0,
                            display:false,
                            drawBorder: false,
                            drawOnChartArea: false,
                        },
                        ticks: {
                            show: false,
                            display:false,
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a better way to do it, but the simplest thing I could think of is to update the dataset according to our needs.

Initially, we can keep all data elements equal and then gradually change them as we want.

Here is a simple solution that I managed to code [link](https://jsfiddle.net/57no9xgs/).

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myChart');
var dataPoints = [65, 59, 30, 81, 56, 55, 40];
var chartData = [];
chartData.length = dataPoints.length;
chartData.fill(nthSmallest(dataPoints, 1));
var doNotOverwrite = [dataPoints.indexOf(chartData[0])];

var data = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)",
            borderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
            borderWidth: 2,
            hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.4)",
            hoverBorderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
            data: chartData,
        }
    ]
};

var myBarChart = Chart.Bar(canvas,{
    data:data,
  options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true,
                suggestedMax: Math.max(...dataPoints)
            }
        }]
    }
}
});

var index = 0;

var interval = setInterval(()=> {
  index++;

  var num = nthSmallest(dataPoints, index);
  appendArray(num);
  doNotOverwrite.push(dataPoints.indexOf(chartData[0]));
  myBarChart.update();
  if(index == dataPoints.length) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}, 1000);

function appendArray(num) {
            for(let i = 0; i< chartData.length; i++) {
        if(!doNotOverwrite.includes(i)) {
            chartData[i] = num;
        }
      }
}

function nthSmallest(numbers, n) {
        numbers = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(numbers));
    var sorted = numbers.sort(function (a, b) {
        return b - a;
    });
    return sorted[sorted.length - n];
}
```

I wrote it in a hurry, so there might be some issues with the code. (Array with repetitive elements will not work as I am using index).

You will also need to update your options for it to work properly.

I know it is not the prettiest solution, but hey it works. :)